# Reduce value of column in another table in java spring boot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I've built backend-process for apps using *spring boot, maven*. 
I have 3 domains (customer, product, order), this the table's columns.

```
        A. Customer:  1. id,
                      2. name,
                      3. address,
                      4. email,
                      5. phone.

        B. Product :  1. id,
                      2. name,
                      3. stock,
                      4. price.

        C. Order   :  1. id,
                      2. customer_id,
                      3. product_id,
                      4. quantity.
```

Each domain has successfully do POST. But in when post an **order**, I need to reduce `product.stock` as much as `order.quantity`.

> What should I do to my code to do this?

This is my **order.java** from domain directory

```
package com.learn.ecommerce.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * A order model.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnoreProperties("")
private Customer customer;

@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnoreProperties("")
private Product product;

@NotNull
@Min(0)
@Column(nullable = false)
private Integer quantity;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public Integer getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
        return true;

    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;

    Order order = (Order) o;

    return !(order.getId() == null || getId() == null) && Objects.equals(getId(), order.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(getId());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Order{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", customer=" + customer +
            ", product=" + product +
            ", quantity=" + quantity +
            '}';
}
```

}

and this is my **OrderServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.kevin.ecommerce.service.impl;

import com.kevin.ecommerce.domain.Order;
import com.kevin.ecommerce.repository.OrderRepository;
import com.kevin.ecommerce.service.OrderService;
import com.kevin.ecommerce.service.dto.OrderDTO;
import com.kevin.ecommerce.service.mapper.OrderMapper;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Slf4j
@Service
@Transactional
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

@Autowired
private OrderRepository orderRepository;

/**
 * Save a order
 *
 * @param orderDTO the entity to save
 * @return the persisted entity
 */
@Override
public OrderDTO save(OrderDTO orderDTO) {
    log.debug("Request to save Order : {}", orderDTO);
    Order order = OrderMapper.INSTANCE.toEntity(orderDTO);
    order = orderRepository.save(order);
    return OrderMapper.INSTANCE.toDto(order);
}

/**
 * Get all of orders
 *
 * @return the list of entities
 */
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<OrderDTO> findAll() {
    log.debug("Request to get all Orders");
    return orderRepository.findAll().stream()
            .map(OrderMapper.INSTANCE::toDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
}

/**
 * Get specific order
 *
 * @param id the id of entity
 * @return the entity
 */
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Optional<OrderDTO> findOne(Long id) {
    log.debug("Request get Order : {}", id);
    return orderRepository.findById(id)
            .map(OrderMapper.INSTANCE::toDto);
}

/**
 * Delete specific order
 *
 * @param id the id of entity
 */
@Override
public void delete(Long id) {
    log.debug("Request to delete Order : {}", id);
    orderRepository.deleteById(id);
}

/**
 * Get all of orders by page
 * @param pageable
 * @return
 */
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<OrderDTO> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
    log.debug("pageable");
    return orderRepository.findAll(pageable).map(OrderMapper.INSTANCE::toDto);
}
```

}

**OrderRepository.java**

```
package com.nostratech.ecommerce.repository;

import com.nostratech.ecommerce.domain.Order;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
}
```

**ProductRepository.java**

```
package com.nostratech.ecommerce.repository;

import com.nostratech.ecommerce.domain.Product;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
}
```

I know I should add the code in `public OrderDTO save`, but I'm new in java-backend and I don't what should I do.

Thanks

Comment: Your assumption is right in the OrderServiceImpl.save you should add the logic to fetch the Product and decrease the amount. But keep in mind that if you use this save functionality for updates as well you first have to check by how much you need to decrease the stock amount.

Comment: "have to check by how much you need to decrease the stock amount"?, If i'm not misunderstand, I decrease the stock amount as much as order.quantity, and I've got that value. I've got the logic, but I dont know yet how to implement it in java. Last 2 years I only use PHP for development.

Comment: Do you have a repository for maintaining the product catalog, you should use this repository to fetch the product attach it to the order and decrease the count and save it. If you do not have a separate repository for Product then the code you posted will create a new product every time a order is created in the database.

Comment: I've check your code below, I forget to tell. In frontend, there will be a product validation. So, customer can't buy product more than product stock. I have separate repository. I've added the Product Repository in my question.

Comment: First rule of development, never trust anything that comes into an API. So you must assume that the call to the back end can be manipulated. The answer I gave still applies, since you need to fetch the product from the DB to manipulate the current stock amount.

Comment: Thanks for the learn @GerbenJongerius :) I've tried your suggestion code and got an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your question lets focus solely on the save method of the OrderServiceImpl. What needs to happen is that you need to fetch an existing product from the database (to prevent creating new entries using the save of the Order). That existing product should then be attached to the order and all manipulations of the stock should happen on that entity.

```
public OrderDTO save(OrderDTO orderDTO) {
   log.debug("Request to save Order : {}", orderDTO);
   Product purchased = productRepository.findById(orderDTO.getProduct().getId());
   Order order = OrderMapper.INSTANCE.toEntity(orderDTO);
   Objects.requireNonNull(purchased, "You cannot buy a non existing product");

   // now prevent Hibernate from creating a new product in the database (and the user from manipulating the product)
   order.setProduct(purchased);
   purchased.setStock(purchased.getStock() - order.getQuantity());

   // this save operation will also trigger the product to be saved (cascading), but it is cleaner to explicitly trigger a save operation.
   order = orderRepository.save(order);
   productRepository.save(purchased);
   return OrderMapper.INSTANCE.toDto(order);
}
```

Comment: `Product purchased = productRepository.findById(orderDTO.getProduct().getId());` I got issue in there, I can't find `get.Id()`. And are you sure it's product not purchased in `product.setStock(product.getStock() - order.getQuantity());`?

Comment: You are right it is purchased for setStock. I am assuming the the product that you receive in the application from the front-end has the product id contained in it. How are you otherwise going to identify which product has been purchased?

Comment: Your assume is right, backend get product_id from front-end. And your code has fixed my issue :) thankyou somuch.